# Checkbox value is not passed properly to the backend API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a registration page created in ReactJS. One of the fields is a checkbox `isadult`. When I click on `Register` button and save the fields in a database (MongoDB), the value of `isadult` appears as [Object object] instead of a concrete value: True or False.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Paper, makeStyles, Grid, TextField, Button, Switch } from '@material-ui/core';
import config from '../../config/config.json';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        minWidth: '300px',
        width: '50%',
        padding: '20px 20px 20px 20px',
        margin: 'auto'
    }
}));

const Register = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
    const [isadult, setIsAdult] = React.useState('');

    const handleChangeIsAdult = (event) => {
        setIsAdult({
          ...isadult, 
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    const handleRegister = () => {
        if (username && password) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('username', username);
            formData.append('password', password);
            formData.append('isadult', isadult);
            axios.post(config.api.url + '/auth/register', formData)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        }
    }

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <div >
                <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
                    <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                        <TextField
                            id="username"
                            label="Username"
                            type="email"
                            fullWidth
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                            autoFocus />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
                    <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                        <TextField
                            id="password"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            fullWidth />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
                    <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                        <label>Is adult?</label>
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                handleChangeIsAdult({
                                target: {
                                    name: event.target.name,
                                    value: event.target.checked,
                                },
                                });
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container justify="center" style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
                    <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
                        onClick={handleRegister}
                    >
                        Register
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: You are passing an object to the `setIsAdult` method, so `isadult` becomes an object. Why are you doing that? Do you have multiple checkboxes?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: No, I only have 1 checkbox. Could you please tell me what would be a proper approach? Thanks.

Comment: If `isadult` is supposed to be a boolean in your `formData`, then all you need to do is `setIsAdult(event.target.value);`

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: Thanks, it helped. However, I cannot register if `isadult` is unchecked (i.e. `false`). In this case, just nothing happens, no error, nothing. It looks like the register request is blocked somewhere, when checkbox is unchecked. Do you know why it may happen? P.S. I check check and uncheck to be able to save `false`.

Comment: I have no idea what your register API expects or how it works but I did notice that the `isadult` boolean is initialized as a string, have you tried `const [isadult, setIsAdult] = React.useState(false);` instead?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: It works now. Thank you so much! Would you like to post an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I just did, I hope it clarifies the issues you are facing in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `isadult` state property is intended for use in the checkbox input, it needs to be declared and updated as a boolean.

You are declaring the propery as follows:

```js
const [isadult, setIsAdult] = React.useState('');
```

The initial assignment is the empty string (`''`), which may cause issues with other places in your application code if they expect that property to be of type boolean. What you should do instead is start it off as a boolean:

```js
const [isadult, setIsAdult] = React.useState(false);
```

Now, the main problem you are facing is the fact that the form data is being serialized with `isadult` being an object. This problem is coming from the fact that you are assigning an object to it through `setIsAdult`:

```js
setIsAdult({
    ...isadult, 
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
});
```

The state property setter appends whatever value is passed to it directly to the property it is attached to. It works differently from `setState` that expects a state object. The right way to use the method in this case is:

```js
setIsAdult(event.target.value);
```

Here, `event.target.value` contains exactly the checkbox `checked` boolean value that should go into `isadult`. Now, this property is serialized correctly as a boolean in your `formData`.