# Why axios post request does not create an object? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working with **react** and I want to implement a post request with **axios**. I have tried several ways, but I don't know why after clicking on submit button no object is returned. Here is my code:

```
export default function NewRequestForm(props) {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
    const [city, setCity] = useState('');
    const [arrival_date, setArrivalDate] = useState('')
    const [departure_date, setDepartureDate] = useState('');
    const [arrival_date_is_flexible, setIsArrDateFelxible] = useState(false);
    const [departure_date_is_flexible, setIsDptDateFelxible] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const handleChangeCountry = (event) => {
        setCountry(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeCity = (event) => {
        setCity(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeArrivalDate = (event) => {
        setArrivalDate(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeDepartureDate = (event) => {
        setDepartureDate(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeMessage = (event) => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeIsArrDateFlexible = (event) => {
        setIsArrDateFelxible(event.target.value);
    };
    const handleChangeIsDptDateFlexible = (event) => {
        setIsDptDateFelxible(event.target.value);
    };
    
    const [values, setValues] = useState(intialState);
    
    const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [prop]: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    // Data Validation and Send to Backend
    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDafault();
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/announcement/create", {
            country : country,
            city : city,
            arrival_date: arrival_date,
            departure_date: departure_date,
            arrival_date_is_flexible: arrival_date_is_flexible,
            departure_date_is_flexible: departure_date_is_flexible,
            message: message,
            })
            .then((res) =>{
                console.log(res.data)
            });
        }


    const handleClose = () => {
        props.setOpen(false);
    };

    const onCancle = () => {
        props.setRequestData({});
        setValues(intialState);
    };

    return (
        <Dialog 
            open={props.open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
            >
                <Box className="add-request-center-element" sx={{ m: 2, maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                    <Box className="request-management-add-request">
                        <Grid container spacing={3}>
                            <Grid item xl={12} lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                <Box className="add-request-center-element">
                                    <form className="add-request-form">
                                        <Box>
                                            <Box className="add-request-center-element form-title">
                                                <h1 style={{ marginBottom: "3rem"}}>Enter The Trip Info</h1>
                                            </Box>
                                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                                {/* country name */}
                                                <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <FormControl sx={{width: "100%"}}>
                                                        <TextField 
                                                            id="new-request-country"
                                                            name="country"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="Country"
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            inputProps={{maxLength: 20}}
                                                            onChange={handleChangeCountry}
                                                            required/>
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* city name */}
                                                <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <FormControl sx={{width: "100%"}}>
                                                        <TextField 
                                                            id="new-request-city"
                                                            name="city"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="City"
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            inputProps={{maxLength: 20}}
                                                            onChange={handleChangeCity}
                                                            required/>
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* Arrival Date */}
                                                <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1 }}
                                                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                                                className="rtlDatePicker">
                                                        <DatePicker 
                                                            animations={[
                                                                transition({
                                                                    from: 35,
                                                                    transition: "all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.335, 0.010, 0.030, 1.360)",
                                                                })
                                                            ]}
                                                            style={{ width: "100%"}}
                                                            inputClass="new-request-date-picker-input"
                                                            className="date-picker"
                                                            format="YYYY/MM/DD"
                                                            name="arrival_date"
                                                            calendarPosition="bottom-end"
                                                            placeholder="Arrival Date *"
                                                            hideOnScroll
                                                            editable
                                                            // onChange={handleChangeArrivalDate}
                                                            />
                                                    {/*  arrival date is flexible */}
                                                    <FormControlLabel
                                                        control={<Checkbox 
                                                                    value="arrivaldateisflexible" 
                                                                    color="primary" 
                                                                    onChange={handleChangeIsArrDateFlexible}
                                                                    />}
                                                        label="Arrival date is flexible"
                                                    />
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* Departure Date */}
                                                <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1 }}
                                                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                                                    className="rtlDatePicker">
                                                        <DatePicker 
                                                            animations={[
                                                                transition({
                                                                    from: 35,
                                                                    transition: "all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.335, 0.010, 0.030, 1.360)",
                                                                })
                                                            ]}
                                                            style={{ width: "100%"}}
                                                            inputClass="new-request-date-picker-input"
                                                            className="date-picker"
                                                            format="YYYY/MM/DD"
                                                            name="departure_date"
                                                            calendarPosition="bottom-end"
                                                            placeholder="Departure Date *"
                                                            hideOnScroll
                                                            editable
                                                            required
                                                            minDate={values.arrival_date}
                                                            // onChange={handleChangeDepartureDate}
                                                            />
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                    {/* departure date is  flexible */}
                                                    <FormControlLabel
                                                        control={<Checkbox 
                                                                    value="arrivaldateisflexible" 
                                                                    color="primary"
                                                                    onChange={handleChangeIsDptDateFlexible}
                                                                    />}
                                                        label="Departure date is flexible"
                                                    />
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* Travelers count */}
                                                {/* message */}
                                                <Grid item xl={12} lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <FormControl sx={{width: "100%"}}>
                                                        <TextField 
                                                            id="new-request-message"
                                                            name="message"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            label="Message"
                                                            variant="outlined"
                                                            multiline 
                                                            fullWidth="true"
                                                            size="medium"
                                                            rows={10}
                                                            maxRows={10}
                                                            onChange={handleChangeMessage}
                                                            />
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* Confirm Button */}
                                                <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant="contained"
                                                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                                                        type="submit"
                                                        onClick={onSubmit}
                                                    >
                                                        Submit the information
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                                {/* Quit */}
                                                <Grid sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }} item xl={6} lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        sx={{
                                                        width: "1000%",
                                                        }}
                                                        type="submit"
                                                        onClick={onCancle}
                                                    >
                                                        Quit
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Box>
                                    </form>
                                </Box>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
        </Dialog>
        
    );

}
```

And this is the code where I call `NewRequestForm` component:

```
 export default function HeaderComponent(props) {
        const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
        const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState({});
    
    const openCreateRequest = (event) => {
        setOpen(true);
        setDisabled(false);
    }
    const header = (
        <div className="table-header">
            <div>
            <Button
                varient="contained"
                size="large"
                style={{ minWidth: 150 }}
                onClick={(e) => openCreateRequest()}>
                    Add New Request
            </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    return (
        <div className="datatable-crud-demo">
            <div className="card">
                <Grid sx={{ marginTop: 2 }} container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <DataTable
                            header={header}>
                        </DataTable>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
            <NewRequestForm 
                open={open}
                setOpen={setOpen}
                disabled={disabled}
                setDisabled={setDisabled}
                setRequestData={setRequestData}
                requestData={requestData}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Before submitting the info:
[image]

After submitting the info:
[image]

And also I don't know why the value of my `checkboxes` are not saved, because based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63299150/20285050), there must not be a problem with reading their values.
I was searching the net for two days, and tried many solutions. But no one of them does not solve my problem. I will be really grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: `preventDafault` should be `preventDefault`

Comment: I have added a new post for new error. May you please take a look at it?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/75787439/20285050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you click the submit button the form will send a get request.

`<form className="add-request-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>`

If a button type is button it will trigger the form onSubmit, remove the `onClick={onSubmi}` from the button and you good to go.

You can see the error, `e.preventDefault() is not a function.`

Use typescript and you will always avoid these little mistakes.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I will change it, but now I faced with another error. I will change my question. Thanks.

Comment: I have added another question for new error. May you please take a look at it.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/75787439/20285050

Answer (score 1):

In the `onSubmit` function you call `e.preventDafault` instead of `e.preventDefault`. Because of this it is reloading the page and not calling your `POST` and calling the `GET` that it calls on page load.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I will change it, but now I faced with another error. I will change my question. Thanks.

Comment: I think in your handler you want to use `e.target.checked`

Comment: I have added another question for new error. May you please take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75787439/20285050